# Obj-C set value to real object sent as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, reference

I cant set new value to object sent as parameter to method. It looks like this:

```
- (void)updatePlayerWithOldSong:(id<ISong>)song
                     withNewSong:(id<ISong>)newSong{

    song = newSong; // -> here I want to change real object sent as parameter - in this case _chosenSong
    // more stuff here
}
```

and when I invoke:

```
[self updatePlayerWithOldSong:_chosenSong withNewSong:newSong];
```

Its not working as I expected. `_chosenSong` object isn't changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all you are doing is copying the object references over each other:

```
- (void)updatePlayerWithOldSong:(id<ISong>)song
                     withNewSong:(id<ISong>)newSong{

    song = newSong;    // Has no effect
}
```

You could pass a pointer-to-pointer (`id` is actually a `typedef`'d pointer) I guess:

```
- (void)updatePlayerWithOldSong:(id<ISong> *)song
                     withNewSong:(id<ISong>)newSong{
    NSAssert(song != NULL, @"Don't pass NULL");
    *song = newSong;
    // more stuff here
}
```

and use it like this:

```
[self updatePlayerWithOldSong:&_chosenSong withNewSong:newSong];
```

It seems overly-complicated though; what's wrong with:

```
_chosenSong = newSong;
[self updatePlayer];
```

or better still, create a custom setter method for the `chosenSong` property and have that call `[self updatePlayer]` and simply use `self.chosenSong = song;`.